# Alert Mechanism for a DataWarehouse

Tags: data-warehouse

We are an operational Data Warehouse.  We have a Batch Control table that holds the following information

1. The file name that was processed into the warehouse.
2. The Date and Time the batch process Started.
3. The number of rows processed and the time taken.

We are thinking of building an alerting mechanism that would basically raise an alert in any of the following anomalous situations(by analyzing past data):

1. A file did not arrive.
2. A file took more than the average time to process.
3. A file has very low or very high row row counts.

What would be the best way to solve this problem.  Is this a candidate for machine learning?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a candidate for machine learning?

Not really.  You have to store certain information about the files processed into the data warehouse.

> A file did not arrive.

You have to have a schedule of files listing when the next file is due to arrive.  If the file is more than 5 days late, the scheduler raises an alarm, sends an email, or whatever.

> A file took more than the average time to process.

Keep the average processing time in your schedule of files.  When the current processing time is more than 2 standard deviations from the average processing time, raise an alarm.

> A file has very low or very high row row counts

Keep the average row count in your schedule of files.  When the current row count is more than 2 standard deviations from the average row count, raise an alarm.

I chose 2 standard deviations from the mean as an exceptional case.  Feel free to adjust this to be more or less sensitive to deviations.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do have one question. 

If a particular batch had an exceptionally high row-count, do I include them in my average calculation?  Is there a rule around this?

Comment: @Gilbert if the row count or processing time do not follow normal distribution, the SD can be mis-leading...

Comment: @Anand Kannan: I'd say, no, but you know your data better than I do.

Comment: @Marmite Bomber: My guess is that the average row count and the average processing time would increase over time.  Yes, that's not a normal distribution.  Still, the standard deviation can be useful for determining an abnormal row count or an abnormal processing time.

Comment: @Gilbert trend is an other important theme. My point was to check the distribution first. E.g. if you have large files during business hours and small files else an alternative approach to SD will be required.

Answer (score 0):

1) Start with *human learning* first.

Plot the time series of the processed files (row number as a function of the processing time).

Plot the distribution (or histogram) of the row numbers

Plot the distribution (or histogram) of the time interval between the processing

Plot the function of the processing time dependent on the row count.

Do you see some patterns in time series? Is there a time of a day resp. weekday periodicity? Do you see a trend?

Is the function of the processing time a continuous function or simple a scatter plot of points?

The clearly you see some pattern and thresholds, the easily you will be able to implement the checks.

2) collect the *history of failures*

Extend your metadata with the status of processing - OK or cause of failure.
This will enable to draw your graphics in two colors (positive / negative cases) and help you to decide if you can draw threshold lines (curves) between them.

You will also be able to apply [supervised learning algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning)